# Page is opening but search is not working when i am using {% for i in kitty_list %} but in case of {% for i in kitty %} then NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In the below scenario, the page is opening but search functionality is not working when i am using `{% for i in kitty_list %}` in the template.  However, when i am using `{% for i in kitty %}` then I get a `NoReverseMatch` error.

```
Url: path('kitty_view',views.kitty_view,name='kitty_view')
View: kitty_list = kitty_list.filter(status =  status1)
      kittys = kitty.objects.all()
      ctx = {'kitty': kitty_list,'kitty_code':kittys}    
      return render(request, 'kitty/kitty_view.html', ctx)
```

This is the HTML page which is giving `NoReverseMatch` error when `{% for i in kitty %}` is used. When i am using `{% for i in kitty_list %}` then the page is rendering but the search button is not working.

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<form class="form-signin" action="{% url 'kitty_view' %}" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="mb-3">
            <select class="custom-select center-block" name="code1" id="code1">
                <option value="">Choose Kitty...</option>
                {% for j in kitty_code %}
                <option value="{{ j.code }}"> {{ j.code|add:' - '|add:j.name }} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" name="nam" id="nam" class="form-control-sm center-block" placeholder="Name" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <select class="custom-select center-block" name="stat" id="stat" placeholder="Status">
                <option value="">Choose Status...</option>
                <option>A</option>
                <option>I</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">           
            <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-info " role="button">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Kitty Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>

    {% if kitty %}  

    {% for i in kitty_code %}

    <tbody>
        <tr>            
            <td>{{ i.id }} </td>
            <td>{{ i.code }} </td>
            <td>{{ i.name }} </td>   

        </tr>
    </tbody>

    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the template file, you need to modify the below line. `{% url 'kitty_view' %}` to `{% url '<app_name>:kitty_view' %}`. If this would not work then, please give me an error in more detail.

Comment: I found out the error. It was because of the below commented lines. I thought it wont have any effect if commented lines will be there. I solved the issue by deleteting below lines from the template.<!-- <td><a href="{% url 'kitty' i.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Details</a> </td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'kitty' i.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a></td> -->